# Using Rsnapshot with sync_first, link_dest, and use_lazy_deletes

Tags: linux, backup, rsnapshot

I've set up rsnapshot with the configuration below and it seems to work fine. However, if I understand what I have read correctly, in the rsnapshot docs and other tutorials, the operation would be more robust with these options added:

```
link_dest 1
sync_first 1
use_lazy_deletes    1
```

However when I enabled these, particularly sync_first, it does not seem to operate correctly. There are no errors, but nothing seems to happen (see last code block below). Configtest succeeds fine. I suspect I am missing something about how sync_first is to be used. I would like to know first if these three options are indeed beneficial when used together (no conflicts) and secondly, is there a difference in the way I must call rsnapshot in cron after enabling sync_first?

This is installed on Ubuntu 14.04 with rsnapshot 1.3.1 and rsync has the link_dest option. Thanks for any direction on this, the official docs are a bit dry.

**Conf**

```
    config_version  1.2
    snapshot_root   /srv/rsnapshot/
    no_create_root  0
    cmd_cp      /bin/cp
    cmd_rm      /bin/rm
    cmd_rsync   /usr/bin/rsync
    cmd_ssh /usr/bin/ssh
    cmd_logger  /usr/bin/logger
    cmd_du      /usr/bin/du
    cmd_rsnapshot_diff  /usr/bin/rsnapshot-diff

    retain      HoursAgo    6
    retain      DaysAgo     7
    retain      WeeksAgo    4
    #retain monthly 3

    verbose     5
    loglevel    3
    logfile /var/log/rsnapshot.log
    lockfile    /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
    rsync_long_args --stats --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded
    ssh_args    -p 22

    # host.mydomain.net
    backup      root@host.mydomain.net:/etc/        host.mydomain.net/
    backup      root@host.mydomain.net:/srv/www/        host.mydomain.net/
    backup_script       /usr/bin/ssh root@host.mydomain.net "rm -rf /var/local/mysqlbak/"       unused/
    backup_script       /usr/bin/ssh root@host.mydomain.net "/usr/local/bin/mysql_bak.sh"       unused1/
    backup      root@host.mydomain.net:/var/local/mysqlbak/     host.mydomain.net/mysql/
```

**Cron**

```
 0     */4    * * *    root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot hourly 2>&1  | \/usr/local/bin/rsnapreport.pl | mail -s "Hourly Backup" myemail@domain.com
 30     3     * * *    root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily 2>&1  | \/usr/local/bin/rsnapreport.pl | mail -s "Daily Backup" myemail@domain.com
 0      3     * * 1    root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot weekly 2>&1  | \/usr/local/bin/rsnapreport.pl | mail -s "Weekly Backup" myemail@domain.com
```

Results of running with all three extra options enabled:

```
root@backup:~# rsnapshot HoursAgo
require Lchown
Lchown module loaded successfully
Setting locale to POSIX "C"
echo 3567 > /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
mv /srv/rsnapshot/HoursAgo.3/ /srv/rsnapshot/HoursAgo.4/
mv /srv/rsnapshot/HoursAgo.2/ /srv/rsnapshot/HoursAgo.3/
mv /srv/rsnapshot/HoursAgo.1/ /srv/rsnapshot/HoursAgo.2/
mv /srv/rsnapshot/HoursAgo.0/ /srv/rsnapshot/HoursAgo.1/
No directory to delete: /srv/rsnapshot/_delete.3567
rm -f /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
/usr/bin/logger -i -p user.info -t rsnapshot /usr/bin/rsnapshot HoursAgo: \
    completed successfully
```

This happens instantly, with no connection to the remote and no time to check changed files.

**Update:** I found some additional information on sync_first in the Ubuntu pages on rsnapshot. I've edited my cron by adding `rsnapshot sync &&` in front of the `hourly` line:

```
 0 */4 * * * root /usr/bin/rsnapshot sync && /usr/bin/rsnapshot hourly 2>&1  | \/usr/local/bin/rsnapreport.pl | mail -s "Hourly Backup" myemail@domain.com
```

This seems to work when I ran it manually.

---

I would still like to know: **Are these three extra options advantageous used together?**

I may also dump the stats so I only get an email in case of error.

Comment: I don't know which version of rsnapshot you have but reading the `man rsnapshot` in section `sync_first` you could see that you can enable it into rsnapshot.conf instead of adding it into your cron job

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `rsnapshot sync` before calling `rsnapshot <level>`.

Comment: Could you comment a bit more the reason of calling this before?

Comment: If you set `sync_first 1` it means that you take responsibility for calling `rsnapshot sync` manually before calling the other retention levels. Calling the other levels simply rotates the files and without any sync (because you told it you'd manually call sync first).